# Error in Publishing the xamarin android code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am trying to publish the xamarin android code in release mode using visual studio through Tool >> Android >> publish android app option. But it's giving issue while i publish the code

[image]

[image]

I have tried again and again but code is giving issue please check the circle error message.

Before 4-5 days back i am following this procedure then it was working fine but now i am trying to publish the app then it's giving issue

Please provide me solution of this issue so that i can upload my app on google play

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your build output? It's shown in the tab right above your blue circle.

Comment: please check the build output. I have attached the output screen along with post

Comment: The proper output message here would most likely be included in the "Xamarin" or "Xamarin Diagnostics" output panel. You can then find the complete log by going to Help -> Xamarin -> Open Logs. You can then paste those items above.

Comment: Please check the logs file i have attached log file with post

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Close the XAmarin Studio/ Visual Studio
2. Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in Command Prompt
3. type adb kill-server
4. type adb start-server.
5. Restart your device/emulator
6. Re-run your code. Hopefully it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Java 7 jdk and install Java 8 jdk. Reboot, recompile and retry.